# To have rounded corners to the inner margin of a button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap button with rounded corner border. I want to make the inner part of the button inside the border rounded corners too instead of a rectangle.

This is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/The_Outsider/3wcfyfv4/). Basically I want the inner border to be similar to how the outer black border is instead of being a rectangle.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Block level button</button>
```

CSS:

```
.btn-primary, .btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary:visited 
{
background-color: #00A0AF !important;
background: linear-gradient(#00A0AF, #00ffff);
}
.btn-primary {
border: 5px solid #000000;
color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: By elliptical do you mean with rounded corners?

Comment: @G.Hunt Yes Rounded corners is appropriate. I want rounded corners on the inner border of the black border similar to how the outer border is. Have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Interesting how your black border disappears in a `<>` snippet here unless I add !important to the border....

Comment: @mplungjan Yeah I wasn't sure too as to what was happening. I tried to use the SO provided snippet option but it didn't work as the fiddle so went ahead and put the fiddle link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The css `border-radius` property is what you want.

Adding `border-radius: 10px;` to the `.btn-primary` class will do it.

Demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3wcfyfv4/1/).

Comment: I am curious why the black border does not appear at SO in the snippets unless I add !important: `.btn-primary {
  border: 5px solid #000000 !important;
  color: #000000;
  border-radius: 10px !important;
}`